# Request method 'POST' not supported. 500 Internal server ERRor Spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-web

I am writing a new API for my web-service.I had already tried all other stackoverflow links related to this.But problem remains.

The Problem is :
When I try to hit my spring-boot application using :

```
curl -v -XPOST http://localhost:9081/postpayment/v1/invoice/djhbjsd/send
```

I get following response :

```
 Trying ::1...
 Connected to localhost (::1) port 9081 (#0)
 POST /postpayment/v1/invoice/djhbjsd/send HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhost:9081
 User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
 Accept: */*

 HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
 Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 Date: Mon, 27 Feb 2017 06:21:43 GMT
 Connection: close

 Closing connection 0
 {"timestamp":1488176503569,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/postpayment/v1/invoice/djhbjsd/send"}
```

My Controller is :

```
@RestController
public class PostPaymentApiController {


     @ResponseBody
     @RequestMapping(value = "/postpayment/v1/invoice/{invoiceGUID}/send", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ResponseEntity<String> sendPaymentConfirmation(
        @PathVariable("invoiceGUID") String invoiceGUID) throws Exception {

        try {
           //logic

        } catch (Exception e) {

            LOGGER.error(invoiceGUID+" Error in sending payment confirmation",e);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(invoiceGUID+" "+e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(invoiceGUID+" payment confirmation sent successfully",HttpStatus.OK);
     }

}
```

Error in log :

```
: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request method 'POST' not supported] with root cause
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.WebContentGenerator.checkRequest(WebContentGenerator.java:301) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:229) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcChildContextConfiguration$CompositeHandlerAdapter.handle(EndpointWebMvcChildContextConfiguration.java:266) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

one more thing .I am getting following response on management port. when I hit on server port, i am getting 404.My application.yml contains:

```
    server.port: 9080
    management.port: 9081
```

Comment: Why did you add @Configuration to your RestController?

Comment: ``@ResponseBody`` in ``@RestController`` is redundant btw

Comment: removed @Configuration from controller.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use [Spring Boot Actuator](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators) because it supposed to used for monitoring your application

Comment: we are using it for health-Check and for some other metrices.

Comment: With my understanding, you are implementing endpoint in Spring boot Actuator in a wrong way. Take a look at my link above to know how to create new custom endpoint.

Comment: I don't want to end new endpoint through Spring boot Actuator .I am trying to expose to new rest end point to my users.Am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rest controller include @Configuration and handler method include @ResponseBody which is not necessary in @RestController so remove @Configuration and @ResponseBody from your controller

Comment: what is your project name or can you upload folder structure of your project

Comment: this repo is not public .you cannot see the repo.btw the project name is "postpayment"

Comment: plz try this in your rest client (postman) i think this will work postpayment/postpayment/v1/invoice/{invoiceGUID}/send or update handler method to @RequestMapping(value="/v1/invoice/{invoiceGUID}/send").... hope it work

Comment: just tried.not working.But I am curious to know , why you added postpayment ahead of uri.

Comment: project name is root URL for Spring MVC application